# How to use value within JS forms and onSubmit. Do I NEED a submit button?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms

### Story:

I have a form, and I want to do things with the values of that form. For background, I'm using react and react-bootstrap to make this form, though I'm more than willing to use a simple form (without react-bootstrap) if it proves simpler.

#### My form:

```js
<form>
    <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect" className={classes.formGroup}>
        <ControlLabel className={classes.exportMessage}>Export</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl className={classes.selectControl} ref='exportType'
            componentClass="select" placeholder="Choose Option">
            <option value="text">Plain text</option>
            <option value="html">Simple HTML</option>
        </FormControl>
    </FormGroup>
    <Button className={'cdm-btn' + ' ' + classes.modalButton} bsStyle='default'
            onClick={this.handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
    <Button className={'cdm-btn' + ' ' + classes.modalButton} bsStyle='primary'
            type='submit' onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
        <FontAwesome className={classes.download} name="download" />Export</Button>
</form>
```

#### Details

- I have 1 input of type `select` (not sure if I'm saying this correctly?)
- This form is within a modal that pops up after clicking a button and `handleClose` closes the modal.
- I want to be able to use the `value` of the `select` as a parameter in a fetch call for later.

  - *I'm having trouble getting this value*

## What I'm doing:

On submit:

```js
handleOnSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // formSelectValue = ???
    console.log(this.refs.exportType);
    // fetchAndDownloadExportFile(listOfItems, formSelectValue);
    this.handleClose();
}
```

This isn't working. the ref isn't output to the console. The page refreshes, but just before it does, I receive an error in the console:

`Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrent' of undefined at e (chrome-extension://blahblah)`

#### What I've Tried:

I tried removing `type="submit"` from the `Export` button, using `onClick` instead, and it does then print out the ref'd FormControl, but I don't see anything indicating which of the two options I've selected.

## Final:

All I want is to be able to select one of two options from a dropdown, plain text `value="text"` or simple html `value="html"` and then pass that value as a parameter into a function, (unrelated) which I can then use in a fetch.

Other possibly useful info: I'm fetching from an API endpoint with

```java
@RequestMapping(
    value = '/api/export',
    method = RequestMethod.POST,
    consumes = [MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE],
    produces = [MediaType.TEXT_HTML_VALUE, MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE]
)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to append form data in an Axios Post request in REACT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59512314/how-to-append-form-data-in-an-axios-post-request-in-react)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this the react way, which is keeping the value of the select input in a state and retrieving it whenever you need it. To keep the select value in a state, add an onChange event handler on the select input like this:

```
<FormControl className={classes.selectControl} componentClass="select" placeholder="Choose Option" onChange={this.handleChange} name="mySelectInput">
```

Notice I have added a `name property` to the select input

With the`handleChange` as shown below:

```
handleChange = (evt)=> { // If you are using typescript, type evt like this evt: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
}
```

The handleChange function will save the value of the select input in the state. Now you can retrieve it and use it like this:

```
const {mySelectInput} = this.state;
```

Below is a full example you can take a look at:

```
    class MyAwesomeComponent extends React.Component {

        constructor() {
          super()
          this.state = {
             mySelectInput: ""
          }
          this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this);
          this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this)
       }

        handleChange = (evt)=> {
           const target = event.target;
           const value = target.value;
           const name = target.name;

           this.setState({
             [name]: value
           });
        }


        handleOnSubmit(e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            // retrieve the value of the select input like this
            const {mySelectInput} = this.state; 

            // and use it here
        }

        render(){
           return(
                <form>
                   <FormGroup controlId="formControlsSelect" className={classes.formGroup}>
                      <ControlLabel className={classes.exportMessage}>Export</ControlLabel>
                       <FormControl className={classes.selectControl} componentClass="select" placeholder="Choose Option" onChange={this.handleChange} name="mySelectInput">
                          <option value="text">Plain text</option>
                          <option value="html">Simple HTML</option>
                       </FormControl>
                  </FormGroup>
                  <Button className={'cdm-btn' + ' ' + classes.modalButton} bsStyle='default'
            onClick={this.handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
                  <Button className={'cdm-btn' + ' ' + classes.modalButton} bsStyle='primary'
            type='submit' onSubmit={this.handleOnSubmit}>
        <FontAwesome className={classes.download} name="download" />Export</Button>
</form>
           )
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `handleOnSubmit(e)` function doesn't have the right event that you are looking for.

You need to watch for the `select input` event with a change handler and then save the updated value somewhere (such as state) so then you can use that value in your `handleOnSubmit` function